# eprint not shown correctly in apsrev style

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, arxiv, doi, url

I am using `natbib` with `apsrev` style for references in article document class:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[]{natbib}       
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true}

\bibliographystyle{apsrev}          

\begin{document}
This is referring to \cite{example}.
\bibliography{eprint_ref}       
\end{document}
```

I am trying to show doi and arXiv links, as written in my `eprint_ref.bib` file:

```
@article{example,
    author =    {A. Author},
    title = {The title of this article},
    journal =   {JCAP},
    volume =    {1212},
    pages = {022},
    year =  {2035},
    doi  =          {10.1088/1475-7516/2012/12/022},
    url  =          {https://doi.org/10.1088/1475-7516/2012/12/022},
    archivePrefix = {arXiv},
    eprint =        {1210.6104},
    primaryClass =  {astro-ph.CO}
}
```

However, the arXiv link is shown wrong pointing to an incorrect address `1210.6104` which is not a url.

doi is printed correctly but after an ugly `URL https://doi.org/` term.
[image]
It is really helpful to me if someone can suggest how to print the arXiv link correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show arXiv identifiers, the most suitable style is `apsrev4-1` instead of `apsrev`.

Two more BibTEX fields `archivePrefix`, and `primaryClass` have been added to `apsrev4-1.bst` in addition to the existing `eprint` field.

The `\eprint` macros can be used to create and hyperlink (if using hyperref) the appropriate arXiv.org identifier as `arXiv:hep-th/1210.6104` or `arXiv:1210.6104 [astro-ph.CO]` with `primaryClass` field in PDF output.

Also, there is no need to include `url` after `doi` field. `doi` is printed and hyperlinked in a better way than `apsrev` case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true}

\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{example,
  Author =  {A. Author},
  title =       {The title of this article},
  journal = {JCAP},
  volume =  {1212},
  pages =   {022},
  year =        {2035},
  doi =         {10.1088/1475-7516/2012/12/022},
  archivePrefix =   {arXiv},
  eprint =      {1210.6104},
  primaryClass =        {astro-ph.CO},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
This is referring to \cite{example}.
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Which prints:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to remove that last whitespace before the period? It leads to weird formatting.

Comment: Also, is there a way *not* to show the primaryclass?

Answer (score 3):

`apsrev` wraps the `eprint` field in an `\eprint` command and provides the following fallback definition for `\eprint`: `\providecommand{\eprint}[2][]{\url{#2}}`.

If you know that all your `eprint`s are only ever arXiv links, you can use the following definition in your preamble (if you load `hyperref`)

```
\newcommand{\eprint}[2][]{\href{https://arxiv.org/abs/#2}{arXiv:~\nolinkurl{#2}}}
```

If you have links to other eprint servers in `eprint` and distinguish them via `archivePrefix`, you'd need to edit `apsrev`, because it discards the info from `archivePrefix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true}

\bibliographystyle{apsrev}

\newcommand{\eprint}[2][]{\href{https://arxiv.org/abs/#2}{arXiv:~\nolinkurl{#2}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{example,
  author        = {A. Author},
  title         = {The title of this article},
  journal       = {JCAP},
  volume        = {1212},
  pages         = {022},
  year          = {2035},
  doi           = {10.1088/1475-7516/2012/12/022},
  url           = {https://doi.org/10.1088/1475-7516/2012/12/022},
  archivePrefix = {arXiv},
  eprint        = {1210.6104},
  primaryClass  = {astro-ph.CO},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
This is referring to \cite{example}.
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Linked arXiv info.]